# Instantiate class to be available to all plugin functions

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm developing a plugin for a site that has to communicate with several non-wp tables in a database. For that I made a class that contains all of the MySQL-related functions.

When you declare a function within a plugin, you can easily call it within a theme. But how to do that with a class?
Is there a way to instantiate it with wordpress init and make it available to plugin(s) and theme(s)?

Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan McCue had a nice idea for his [plugin Hopper](https://github.com/rmccue/Hopper): add a callback for a custom filter to return the current instance.

Sample code for the plugin:

```
class Plugin_Class {
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_filter( 'get_plugin_class', array ( $this, 'provide_instance' ) );
    }

    function provide_instance() {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In a theme or a second plugin you can access the instance now like this:

```
$plugin_class = apply_filters( 'get_plugin_class', NULL );

if ( is_a( $plugin_class, 'Plugin_Class' ) )
{
    // use the plugin class instance
}
```

Comment: Wow, this solution is amazing. I would've never thought of that!
I really love the fact it instantiates the class only once. :) Thank you!!! :)